# tcpdump: syntax error in filter expression: syntax error

Tags: macos, tcpdump

I'm trying to learn how to use tcpdump instead of airport to sniff packets, but I can't figure out a part of the code that I usually find around the internet. I've already been searching for about 2 days for someone that may have made a question similar to my needs, and I've decided to ask the question my self.

```
sudo tcpdump "type mgt subtype beacon and ether src $BSSID" -I -c 1 -i en0 -w beacon.cap
```

I figured out that it is a filter to not have a ton of garbage inside the packets .cap but I don't know why the command line Is returning me:

```
tcpdump: syntax error in filter expression: syntax error
```

Can someone explain me what the filter should do so that maybe I can start trying to figure out by myself how may I fix it, or at least have a different lead to follow to search on the internet

Comment: Did you make sure your `BSSID` variable was defined ? (`export BSSID=<some_source_ip>`)

Comment: yes I did, I thought variables should be enclosed in squared brackets

Comment: What version of `tcpdump` and `libpcap` do you have?  What do you get if just run "sudo tcpdump -i en0 "type mgt"?  If the en0 interface isn't an 802.11 interface, you should get an error of the form, "tcpdump: 802.11 link-layer types supported only on 802.11".  My guess is that the en0 inferface isn't an 802.11 interface.  Run "tcpdump -D" to list interfaces and "tcpdump -i en0 -L" to list the data link types supported by that interface.